# how to minus two dates in Java like 10-11-2007 minus 10-01-2006

Tags: java, android

how to minus date in Java like 10-11-2007 minus 10-01-2006.

I want to get days. How many days difference between them? I check some but there is no option to minus date between two dates and get Days.

How can I get it in Java? Is there any way in Java?